# GroovyClassLoader and imports

Tags: groovy, java-7, groovyshell, groovyclassloader

I am using a GroovyClassLoader in my Java class to parse a certain (ideally complex) groovy file (to be executed in the next step):

**Call in MyClass.java**

```
final Class parsedClass = groovyClassLoader.parseClass(groovyFile);
```

Knowing that:

- Groovy files need to be stored in the filesystem because would need to be change without redeployment.
- This groovy file would need several imports:

**GroovyFile.groovy imports**

```
import com.my.import.one.Import1DTO
import com.my.import.two.Import2DTO
import com.my.import.three.Import3DTO
import com.my.import.four.Import4DTO
import com.my.import.five.Import5DTO
```

When the *parseClass* method is invoked, this exeception raises:

**Exceptions**

```
unable to resolve class com.my.import.one.Import1DTO;
unable to resolve class com.my.import.two.Import2DTO;
unable to resolve class com.my.import.three.Import3DTO;
unable to resolve class com.my.import.four.Import4DTO;
unable to resolve class com.my.import.five.Import5DTO;
```

Can I obtain the behaviour I expect without parse every import class before parse the base class?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example MyClass.java which uses the `addClasspath()` method on `GroovyClassLoader`

```
import groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        GroovyClassLoader groovyClassLoader = new GroovyClassLoader();

        // add "lib" to the classpath
        groovyClassLoader.addClasspath("lib");

        String groovyFile = "GroovyFile.groovy";
        Class parsedClass = groovyClassLoader.parseClass(groovyFile);
        System.out.println("class is " + parsedClass.toString());
    }
}
```

I assume that the DTOs are written in Groovy and that we use "myimport", since "my.import.x" will fail due to illegal syntax. If we have a "lib" directory like so, with compiled classes:

```
lib/com/myimport/one/Import1DTO.groovy
lib/com/myimport/one/Import1DTO.class
lib/com/myimport/two/Import2DTO.groovy
lib/com/myimport/two/Import2DTO.class
```

and that GroovyFile.groovy exists in the main directory. e.g.

```
import com.myimport.one.Import1DTO
import com.myimport.two.Import2DTO

println "hi there"
```

then the above Java code works for me.

I am using Groovy 2.2.1 with groovy-all-2.2.1.jar on the classpath (for GroovyClassLoader).

Comment: Thanks! Continuing with your example, I suppose redeployment is not required If I make some change in Import1DTO.groovy, Import2DTO.groovy or GroovyFile.groovy but, what would happen If I create a new Import3DTO.groovy with the required Import3DTO.class?