# How to use the `addClasspath()` method in GroovyClassLoader

Tags: java, groovy, classpath, groovyclassloader

I need to load a bunch of groovy scripts from DataBase , like this:

```
List<ScriptDAO> scriptList = dataBaseRepository.findAll();
GroovyClassLoader groovyClassLoader = new 
GroovyClassLoader(this.getClass().getClassLoader());
for (ScriptDAO script : CollectionUtils.emptyIfNull(scriptList)) {
     groovyClassLoader.parseClass(script.getContent); 
}
```

When the parseClass method is invoked, this exeception raises:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script_30b09946e4afa374dc45b9929ce7d050.groovy: 3: unable to resolve class com.xxx.groovy.model.RuleDataB
```

I saw this question:[GroovyClassLoader and imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21884218/groovyclassloader-and-imports). I know this error was caused by `RuleDataB` which was not loaded.

Scrips are like this:

```
package com.xxx.groovy.business

import com.google.common.collect.Lists
import com.xxx.groovy.model.RuleDataB
import org.apache.commons.collections4.CollectionUtils


class RuleDataA {

    /**
     * getData
     */
    static List<RuleDataB> getData(List<String> ids) {
        if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(ids)) {
            return Lists.newArrayList()
        }
        return RemoteXXXService.getRuleDataBByIds(ids)
    }
}
```

What confuse me is how to use the `addClasspath()` method. My Scripts are loaded from BD, should I trans `String` into `File`?

I also need to `reload` this groovy class by updating `ScriptDAO`.

Comment: Where  RuleDataB is located?

Comment: Here `List<ScriptDAO> scriptList = dataBaseRepository.findAll();`

Comment: you could parse them in a right order. or you could store all those classes into file system and add the folder as a classpath using addClasspath(). or you could create custom classloader that creates classes on demand by requesting them by name from storage (database)...

Comment: this answer will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32033980/how-compile-groovy-source-but-not-from-filesystem